Field of definition of elliptic curves
Let $a,b$ be positive integers, $F=\mathbb{Q}(a^{1/3},b^{1/2})$. Let $E$ be the elliptic curve defined over $F$ by the cubic equation $$y^2=x^3+3a^{1/3}x+2b^{1/2}.$$
Then the $j$-invariant $j(E) = \frac{1728a}{a+b} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence $E$ has a model defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ up to an isomorphism over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.
The field of definition of $E$ is the smallest field $F'\subseteq F$, such that there exists an elliptic curve $E'$ defined over $F'$, and an isomorphism $E\cong E'\times_{F'}F$ over $F$. My question is how to decide the field of definition of $E$? Is it equal to $F$?

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

The field of moduli of an elliptic curve is always a field of definition, a fact that is not true for abelian varieties of higher dimension. You can use the fact that two elliptic curves are isomorphic over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$, or indeed over any algebraically closed field, if and only if they have the same $j$-invariant, together with the fact that the elliptic curve $$y^2+xy=x^3-\frac{36}{j-1728}x-\frac{1}{j-1728}$$ is an elliptic curve with $j$-invariant equal to $j$. This works in all characteristics, even $2$ and $3$, as long as $j\ne0,1728$. For $j=0$ we can use $y^2+y=x^3$ and for $j=1728$ we can use $y^2=x^3+x$, where if the characteristic is $2$ or $3$, then $1728=0$ and one of those two curves will work.
Addendum: The above general answer does not address your question. Sorry about that. Here is a result showing that in general, the curve that you've written is not $F$-isomorphic to a curve defined over $\mathbb Q$  (with some minor changes of notation).
Theorem: Let $F$ be a field of characteristic not equal to $2$ or $3$, let $a,b\in F^*$, let $A,B\in\overline{F}^*$ satisfy $A^3=a$ and $B^2=b$, and let $K=F(A,B)$. Make the following assumptions:
$$ \pm b\notin{F^*}^2, \quad a\notin{F^*}^3, \quad 4a+27b\ne0. \tag{$*$} $$
Let $E:Y^2=X^3+AX+B$. Then the assumptions $(*)$ imply that there does not exist a $K$-isomorphism from $E$ to an elliptic curve defined over $F$, although since $j(E)\in{F}$, there is an $\overline{F}$-isomorphism to such a curve.
Proof: Fix a Weierstrass equation $E':Y^2=X^3+A'X+B'$ with $A',B'\in{F}$. Then any isomorphism $\phi:E\to{E'}$ has the form $\phi(X,Y)=(u^2X,u^3Y)$ for some $u\in\overline{F}^*$. Hence $A'=u^4A$ and $B'=u^6B$ are in $F$, and so
$$ c := \frac{B'}{A'} = \frac{u^2B}{A} \in F. $$
Raising to the $6$th power and using $A^3=a$ and $B^2=b$ yields
$$ c^6 = \frac{u^{12}b^3}{a^2}, \quad\text{and thus}\quad u^{12} - \frac{a^2c^6}{b^3} = 0. $$
If the isomorphism is defined over $K$, then $u\in{K}$, so in particular
$$ [F(u):F] \le [K:F] \le 6, $$
which implies that the polynomial
$$ T^{12} - \frac{a^2c^6}{b^3} \quad\text{is reducible in $F[T]$, since it has a root $u$ in an extension of degree ${}\le6$.} $$
A standard factorization result (e.g. Lang's Algebra, the section entitled "The Equation $X^n-a-0$'') says that if $\gamma\in{F^*}$ and if $T^{12}-\gamma$ is reducible in $F[T]$, then one of the following is true:
$$ \gamma\in{F^*}^2\quad\text{or}\quad\gamma\in{F^*}^3\quad\text{or}\quad\gamma\in-4{F^*}^4. $$
Taking $\gamma=a^2c^6/b^3$, this gives
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
a^2c^6/b^3\in{F^*}^2 &\Rightarrow b\in{F^*}^2 \quad\text{or}\\
a^2c^6/b^3\in{F^*}^3 &\Rightarrow a\in{F^*}^3 \quad\text{or}\\
a^2c^6/b^3\in-4{F^*}^4 &\Rightarrow a^2bc^2\in-4{F^*}^4 \Rightarrow b\in-{F^*}^2. 
\end{aligned}
$$
The three possibilities are ruled out by ($*$), which proves that $[F(u):F]=12$, contradicting $u\in{K}$.
Remark: This shows that most choices of $a$ and $b$ give an elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+a^{1/3}x+b^{1/2}$ that is not $\mathbb Q(a^{1/3},b^{1/2})$-isomorphic to an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb Q$. With more effort, it should be possible to give a more precise condition that is both necessary and sufficient.

Dear Mr.Silverman, thank you for your answer! But I think my question maybe somewhat different, because I am considering the isomorphism of elliptic curves over $F$, rather than over $\mathbb{\overline{Q}}$.
